# where can I find the extjs css x types

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there an official way to get the x-... (eg x-grid-row-summary) types of components, I am currently using the debugger in chrome and looking at the html in there.

But it feels wrong and that there must be a published list somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only things would be as simple as that. CSS classes are used extensively by ExtJS for correct display of components, and are a hybrid between the component type itself and its state (`focues` would also get a css class).

The example you gave demonstrates it: `x-grid-row-summary` is injected within `AbstractSummary.js`, which is really a feature rather than a component. `x-grid-row-summary` does not have any corresponding css class and isn't included in the default theme's `scss` (under `/resources/themes/stylesheets/ext4/default/`).

So I'm afraid the way you do it is the best way of doing it.

Comment: For this particular example, how will the prettifier guys know what to put in their css files?

Comment: I'm doing exactly what you do - look at the dom. I also use scss (on top to the extjs one - not using the limited mixins that comes with extjs 4) so inspecting the scss of ExtJs sometimes helps to find all possible classes. Lastly, you sometimes need to look at the source code to see what css classes might be added. It's very much a hacking business.